# Aggregate time from 15-minute interval to single hour in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have below table structure in SQL Server:

```
StartDate   Start       End         Sales
==============================================
2020-08-25  00:00:00    00:15:00    291.4200
2020-08-25  00:15:00    00:30:00    401.1700
2020-08-25  00:30:00    00:45:00    308.3300
2020-08-25  00:45:00    01:00:00    518.3200
2020-08-25  01:00:00    01:15:00    247.3700
2020-08-25  01:15:00    01:30:00    115.4700
2020-08-25  01:30:00    01:45:00    342.3800
2020-08-25  01:45:00    02:00:00    233.0900
2020-08-25  02:00:00    02:15:00    303.3400
2020-08-25  02:15:00    02:30:00    11.9000
2020-08-25  02:30:00    02:45:00    115.2400
2020-08-25  02:45:00    03:00:00    199.5200
2020-08-25  06:00:00    06:15:00    0.0000
2020-08-25  06:15:00    06:30:00    45.2400
2020-08-25  06:30:00    06:45:00    30.4800
2020-08-25  06:45:00    07:00:00    0.0000
2020-08-25  07:00:00    07:15:00    0.0000
2020-08-25  07:15:00    07:30:00    69.2800
```

Is there a way to group above data into one hour interval instead of 15 minute interval?
It has to be based on start and end columns.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like the following using `datepart`?

```
select startdate, DatePart(hour,start) [Hour], Sum(sales) SalesPerHour
from t
group by startdate,  DatePart(hour,start)
```